# Formatting of Microsoft speech recognition results (Norwegian)

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

In our ongoing experiments with transcribing video materials using various speech-to-text suppliers, Microsoft seems to be a strong contender regarding the actual word recognition. For English materials, the formatting/punctuation is also quite good, but for Norwegian language materials (which is most relevant to us) there is hardly any formatting/punctuation whatsoever. We're using the C# API SpeechRecognizer, with config.SpeechRecognitionLanguage set to "nb-NO", config.OutputFormat set to OutputFormat.Detailed, and using config.RequestWordLevelTimestamps(). Is there something we can do to improve the formatting of the results?

Also, when retrieving single words w/timestamps (which is one of our requirements), there is no formatting even with English materials. Is there some option we can set to maintain formatting/punctuation when retrieving single words?

Best regards,
Gunnar

Comment: Which result are you using? Lexical, Display, ITN, MaskedITN?

Comment: We're using Display. But except for the very first word being capitalized in the Display and Masked ITN versions, there's no difference in formatting between the result versions, as far as I can tell. (This is for Norwegian; it's a different story with English clips.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft speech formatting support for nb-NO results is indeed very basic at this moment. Display results have basic number formatting and explicit punctuation when requested. Microsoft speech is actively working on improving automatic punctuation and capitalization to improve the results.
Regarding to timestamps, currently it does not produce timestamps for the display level. It may be supported in the future.

Comment: Heidi, thanks for replying! As to my timestamps question, we do get word level timestamps, however, even with English materials (where the display results DO have quite good capitalization/punctuation) the timed single words are unformatted. Is there some config option to keep capitalization/punctuation at the single word level?

Comment: Unfortunately, a simple answer is no for now. The current "single word level" is generated based on the lexical input and persisted that way when it returns the results back after display formatting. Good news is that the work of changing the result payload to include display level words and timing offset is scheduled and you may see it works as you expected in this May.